# Mustache - how can I do something *once* for an iterable?

Tags: templating, mustache

Say I have a `user`, who has many `items`

How can I have a **single** 'Sweet, you have items!', provided there's at last one item in `items`?

```
{{#user.items}}
  Sweet, you have items!
{{/user.items}}
```

**Note**: I know I can create a section that will repeat for each item. But right now I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer (like most things Mustache) is "prepare your view model before rendering" :)

But if you're not into that, you can usually fake it in Mustache.js like this:

```
{{# user.items.0 }}
  Sweet, you have items!
{{/ user.items.0 }}
```

(The more Mustachey way would be to add a `hasItems` property or function to the user and use that instead)

*Edit: `{{# user.items.length }}` does the same thing, and doesn't pollute your context stack quite as much. You should use that instead.*

*Well, really, you should use a view model. But second best would be `user.items.length`.*

Comment: Excellent answer, including the 'what question wanted' way, the right way, and the compromise. Thanks!