# Mustache: if statement and foreach loop on same variable?

Tags: mustache

How do I use both an if statement and a for/each loop on the same variable in Mustache?

I've got a list of links. I'd like to do the following:

```
{{# list }}
List title
<ul>
  {{# list }}
  <li>{{{ text }}}</li>
  {{/ list }}
</ul>
{{/ list }}
```

But if the list is more than one item long, I get multiple copies of `List title` and `<ul>` etc.

How can I only show the list title if the list exists, but also iterate over the list elements, in Mustache?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mustache - how can I do something \*once\* for an iterable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572096/mustache-how-can-i-do-something-once-for-an-iterable)

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question (although - I didn't find that question even after extensive Googling, so I suggest it might be useful to leave this one open for others to find...)

Answer (score 0):

handlebars.js

> Handlebars is largely compatible with Mustache templates.

Look here : http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#conditionals