# Mustache template with label

Tags: php, mustache.php

If I have the following array

```
array (
    'people' => array(
        [0] => array('name'=>'name1'),
        [1] => array('name'=>'name2', 'last' => true)
    )
);
```

and I want to output it using a [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) template so that the final html looks like this:

```
<div>
    Names: name1, name2
</div>
```

Though if the array is empty then it shouldn't output anything.

This is my current template

```
<div>
    {{#people}}
        Names: {{name}}{{^last}}, {{/last}}
    {{/people}}
</div>
```

which outputs

```
<div>
    Names: name1, Names: name2
</div>
```

I understand why it doesn't output what I want but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div>
    {{#people.0}}
        Names:
        {{#people}}
            {{name}}{{^last}}, {{/last}}
        {{/people}}
    {{/people.0}}
</div>
```

The reason you were getting `Names:` written twice was because everything inside `{{#people}}`  and `{{\people}}` is treated as a loop.

Comment: Yes becuase then if there are no people, the `Names:` label will still be there.

Comment: Add a `hasNames` key to your array, or use the hacky `{{# people.0 }}` to check whether it's empty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572096/mustache-how-can-i-do-something-once-for-an-iterable/19577717#19577717

Comment: Or you can use `{{#people.length}}` (updated the answer)

Comment: Sorry - it's php `.length` probably won't work. I'll refer you back to  the comment that @bobthecow made.

Comment: No I can't get `.length` to work but `#people.0` works great, thanks